# Can't access a network share when executing a package from the SSIS Catalog

Tags: sql-server, ssis, access-denied

I'm currently having an issue where I can execute a package perfectly fine from SQL Server Data Tools but get the following error when trying to execute from within the SSIS Catalog:

> File System Task:Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Access to the path '\xxxxxxxx\xxxx\' is denied.".
>   "

I'm logging in to SSMS and SSDT using the same log in details and was under the impression that when executing from the SSIS Catalog the credentials supplied when logging in to SSMS were used?

Just for clarity, I'm talking about executing directly from the menu in SSMS:

[[image: img]]

Comment: Is the path you're trying to access a UNC path, or a mapped drive?  Did you check sharing permissions on both the share itself, and the access rights on the folder?

Comment: UNC path and I have the correct permissions.  The package runs fine when I execute it locally from my machine.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you don't have Kerberos configured on your SQL Server (double hop issue).

Here is the issue logged with MS which has been fixed now.
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/767088/with-the-new-ability-to-execute-ssis-packages-from-tsql-kerberos-delegation-should-be-supported

Here is a great blog post on the details of this:
http://www.sqlscientist.com/2014/01/setup-kerberos-authentication-for-sql.html

Once this is configured, you should be able to remotely kick off the job using a Stored Procedure, or SSMS on your local machine. It will pass your credentials if it is configured correctly, of course you have to make sure you have the proper permissions to access the network resource.

Comment: I have a server with Kerberos properly configured and still the packages execution fail when used from SSISDB. They run properly when run in Visual Studio (same login used for both executions).

Comment: Are you attempting to access a share or resource from another server? You must make sure both your SSIS Server and the resource you're attempting to connect to has Kerberos configured correctly and the domain trusts SQL Server running SSIS to pass the Kerberos ticket.

Comment: Why do you think this is related to kerberos issue? Can you please tell me what you think is hop 1 and hop 2 in the question? The ssis file system task is directly (hop 1) accessing the network file using the credentials of the person executing the package.