# SSIS cannot access folder which everyone has access to

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, network-drive, sql-agent

So we have a network address lets call it the Z drive that everyone has access to.
By everyone I mean the entire organization. For completeness, I actually went ahead and gave access to the actual SQL Server Agent.

The package runs fine on dev, but always fails with

> The directory "Z:\SSIS_Test" does not exist

At first, I thought it was an issue of access. But how can't the SQL Server Agent access an everyone drive?

Also, I went in and run the package on the server myself as the caller and it still failed with same error. What gives? Am I not getting something?

Comment: I'm sure the `Z:` drive is a mapped drive that everyone has a mapping to. What is the UNC path? Try that instead.

Comment: @SS_DBA tried the full UNC path, worked on dev, failed on the sql server :(

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Same error "The directory "\\organization\workgroups\services\ssis_test" does not exist

Comment: `organization` is a server name?

Comment: @SS_DBA Yes! and thank you! It worked after changing to the UNC full path and also giving access to sql server (SQL SERVICE) to the folder...I don't understand how but it worked that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Possible solutions

#### (1) Granting service accounts

Try giving read/write permissions to the SQL Database Engine Service account `NT SERVICE\MSSQL$<Instance Name>` and `NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT` *(Where `<Instance Name>` should be replaced by the installed instance name)*:

- [Configure File System Permissions for Database Engine Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017)

I was facing the same issue, it looks like the "everyone" permission does not take into consideration service accounts *(I am not sure)*. The issue was solved after granting the database engine and SQL agent service accounts. Also feel free to read more about SQL Server service account in the following documentation:

- [Configure Windows Service Accounts and Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions?view=sql-server-ver15)

#### (2) Mapping drive within SQL Server

You can refer to the following article for more information:

- [Make Network Path Visible For SQL Server Backup and Restore in SSMS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3499/make-network-path-visible-for-sql-server-backup-and-restore-in-ssms/)

**Or you can try to use the full UNC path instead of the mapped drive.**

---

**If these solutions didn't worked**, there are many other suggestions listed in the following answer, you can check it for more information:

- [SSIS File System Task Error while copying files between servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456817/ssis-file-system-task-error-while-copying-files-between-servers/44532223#44532223)

Comment: for some reason NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT and NT SERVICE\MSSQL$OURSQL are not popping up at the EntireDirectory location when I go to search to add them at the folder permissions